# VMware Virtual Machine Power Consumption

Tags: vmware-vsphere, electrical-power

I know there is a way to view the power consumption in Watts for a specific VM, but is there a way to view or output the total power consumption for a set of VMs over a given period?

Answer (score 1):

> I know there is a way to view the power consumption in Watts for a
> specific VM

No there's not, not in vCenter/ESXi anyway. There's something in VMware Aria Operations that may be able to do what you need, if you have that and have filled in all of the various costings.

If not then you could get the whole host's power consumption, add up the total amount of all VM on that's hosts CPU/memory/storage resource utilisation, then determine an given VM's percentage of the host's power consumption and that would vaguely give you what you need, for multiple hosts just do that and add them up.